# Hive: random select different size of samples from group by

Tags: random, group-by, hive

Is it possible to random select different sizes of samples from group by in Hive? For instance, I have a table like this

```
|-----------------|----------------|
|     ID          |     Value      |
|-----------------|----------------|
|    IKJ12        |    5           |
|-----------------|----------------|
|    IKJ12        |    9           |
|-----------------|----------------|
|    IKJ12        |    10          |
|-----------------|----------------|
|    IKJ09        |    7           |
|-----------------|----------------|
|    IKJ09        |    14          |
|-----------------|----------------|
```

I would like to randomly select two samples from `ID = IKJ12` and one sample from `ID = IKJ09`. One possibility is like this.

```
|-----------------|----------------|
|     ID          |     Value      |
|-----------------|----------------|
|    IKJ12        |    5           |
|-----------------|----------------|
|    IKJ12        |    10          |
|-----------------|----------------|
|    IKJ09        |    14          |
|-----------------|----------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please give this a try? I did not find to test it out but i think you will get idea from this.
row number is used to give unique rownum for each id in a partition.
sum is used to get how many elements are there in a partition.

```
select id,value
from 
(select id,value,
row_number() over(partition by id order by id) rn
sum(1) over(partition by id order by id) cnt
from table 
)
where rs.rn<= floor(rand*100)%cnt+1
```